# InvalidVersion: Invalid version: '0.10.1,<0.11' in Colab when trying to "from allennlp.nn.util import sort_batch_by_length, masked_softmax"

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, allennlp

I was using this for a couple of months just fine in Colab. But when I tired to work with it today I saw this error

```
InvalidVersion: Invalid version: '0.10.1,<0.11'
```

the error appears when I try to import form **allennlp.nn.util**

in here:

```
from allennlp.nn.util import sort_batch_by_length, masked_softmax
```

The whole error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidVersion                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-dca1f0a13432> in <module>
      4 import torch.nn as nn
      5 import torch.nn.functional as F
----> 6 from allennlp.nn.util import sort_batch_by_length, masked_softmax
      7 #last_dim_softmax
      8 from torch.nn.utils.rnn import pack_padded_sequence

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/packaging/version.py in __init__(self, version)
    195 
    196 def _legacy_cmpkey(version: str) -> LegacyCmpKey:
--> 197 
    198     # We hardcode an epoch of -1 here. A PEP 440 version can only have a epoch
    199     # greater than or equal to 0. This will effectively put the LegacyVersion,

InvalidVersion: Invalid version: '0.10.1,<0.11'
```

I am using colab GPU,
Python 3.8.10
allennlp==2.7.0

could someone help me with this please?
Appreciate it.

I tried similar errors I found here

```
pip install packaging==21.3
and
pip install torchmetrics==0.6
```

none worked

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that is the whole error traceback message?  I don't see why line 6 would lead directly to line 197 -- there seems to be stuff missing in-between. 
Also, it is quite strange that the arrow pointer on line 197 refers to a blank line...

Comment: yes, I just installed allennlp and I want to import, there is nothing else before that. I think it is related to colab, I think something is clashing with colab and allennlp because when I comment out the "form allennlp import...." line, the file execute but then I cant use sort_batch_by_length, masked_softmax.

Comment: I think this comes from transfromers... see: https://huggingface.co/spaces/rkp74/MCQ-Generation